# Sending multiple responses(res.json) with the same response object in Express.js

Tags: node.js, express

```
res.json(Object.assign({}, cart.generateArray()));
res.json(JSON.stringify(cart.totalPrice));
```

how can i send Sending multiple responses because my code doesn't work

thank you

Comment: plz mention your code so that we can help as per your requirement

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot send multiple responses. You send an object that contains your array and total price:

```
res.json({
    items: cart.generateArray(),
    totalPrice: cart.totalPrice
});
```

Another option would be to make two different requests if you need two responses.

Comment: FWIW, I used Andy's explanation to do  res.json({responseObjects: myArrayOfJSONObjects}) in an Express.JS and Node.JS configuration.  Worked perfectly!